# google script textarea or textbox want not give me text

Tags: javascript, textbox, google-apps-script

How can I get text from textarea or textbox.

```
function myClickHandler() {
    var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
    var textbox = app.getElementById("TextBox1");
    var text = textbox.text;
    textbox.setText(text + "1");
    return app;
}
```

After run of this function is in my textarea: "undefined1".

On googledevelopers help page https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_textbox
is not getText method.

How can I get text from textbox?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_textbox#setValue

Answer (score 2):

It's not `textbox.text`. It should be `textbox.value`.

```
function myClickHandler() {
    var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
    var textbox = app.getElementById("TextBox1");
    var text = textbox.value;
    textbox.setText(text + "1");
    return app;
}
```

Comment: Result is still same. textbox.value return undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
 var text = textbox.value;
```

Comment: Result is still same. textbox.value return undefined

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass a widget's value to a callback handler you must do two things:

1. Assign a name to the widget when you create it. 
   `texbox.setName('foo');`
2. Add the widget as a callback element to the server handler you create.
   `clickHandler.addCallbackElement(textbox);`

If you've done that, then the value of the textbox will be passed in the event parameter of your callback function.

```
function myClickHandler(event) {
  var textboxValue = event.parameters['foo'];
  ...
}
```